# How to get data from mysql reverse foreign key without using the prefetch concept?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models, Like,

```
class User(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'u_users'

class Email(models.Model):
    usr_id = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='usr_id', related_name='emails', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
         managed = True
         db_table = 'u_email'
```

Now i'would like to get list of users with list of email each users have

Sample output.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "fname":"Test User",
      "emails":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "email":"masstmp+2ffj7@gmail.com"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "email":"masstmp+2ffj8@gmail.com"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "fname":"Test User2",
      "emails":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "email":"masstmp+2ffj9@gmail.com"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "email":"masstmp+2ffj10@gmail.com"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But i need to get this output using single query. In raw query i able to write the query and get the output easy. But i want to know about how to do this in ORM.

Please, Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

Comment: Just curious, why is using prefetch not an option?

Comment: Prefetch runs the seperate query right?